# How do I serve my XAMPP files from htdocs/JoesDirectory?

Tags: xampp

I've installed XAMPP as Administator on Windows under `C:\xampp` and everything is working fine, but when I point my web browser to my computer's IP by typing `http://n.n.n.n/` into the URL the browser redirects to `http://n.n.n.n/xampp/` which is where the XAMPP admin panel can be accessed. However, I want users browsing `http://n.n.n.n/` to view my `index.html` / `index.php` file from `C:\xampp\JohnDoesDirectory'`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and change the lines:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

to

```
#DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
#<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/JohnDoesDirectory"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/JohnDoesDirectory">
```

Then restart Apache from the XAMPP Control Panel (by clicking Stop and then Start).

That solves the problem.